# How to use Evaluators in Java to score on a PMML using org.apache.spark?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, scoring, pmml

I've implemented the code for scoring on a provided PMML file and a csv data file (Linear Regression) using Spark and Java. For this I've used jpmml-evaluator-spark and spark-mllib_2.11 maven artifacts, and it works fine.

Now, I'm looking at replacing jpmml-evaluator-spark library, which is AGPL licensed, to something similar may be bundled within org-apache-spark (or any other fully open source option)
I don't see Evaluators for scoring on a PMML available in org.apache.spark group of dependencies. Please confirm if this is correct and suggest some alternative.

```
https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-evaluator-spark
```

This is the PMML evaluator library for the Apache Spark cluster computing system (http://spark.apache.org/) and is AGPL.

Also refer to: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html
These suggest that whatever is packaged along with apache spark includes algorithms and model creation and training, but scoring on the model is not available here & has its dependencies included in the jpmml-evaluator-spark only.

```java
    import org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer;
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;

    import org.jpmml.evaluator.Evaluator;
    import org.jpmml.evaluator.EvaluatorBuilder;
    import org.jpmml.evaluator.LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder;
    import org.jpmml.evaluator.spark.TransformerBuilder;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    EvaluatorBuilder evaluatorBuilder = new LoadingModelEvaluatorBuilder().setLocatable(false)
                        .setVisitors(new DefaultVisitorBattery()).load(pmmlInputStream);
    Evaluator evaluator = evaluatorBuilder.build();
    evaluator.verify();

    TransformerBuilder pmmlTransformerBuilder = new TransformerBuilder(evaluator).withLabelCol("Predicted_SpeciesCategory").exploded(true);

    Transformer pmmlTransformer = pmmlTransformerBuilder.build();
    Dataset<?> resultDataset = pmmlTransformer.transform(csvDataset);
    ...
    ...
```

Maven dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpmml-evaluator-spark</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpmml-sparkml</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

This code still has dependency on org.jpmml library, which I wish to remove. Looking for an alternative using org.apache.spark library to achieve similar results.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [PMML4S-Spark](https://github.com/autodeployai/pmml4s-spark) to evaluate a PMML model against Spark, for example:

```scala
import org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel

val model = ScoreModel.fromInputStream(pmmlInputStream)
val resultDataset = model.transform(csvDataset)
```

If you want to use PMML4S-Spark in Java, it's also easy to use and similar as Scala, for example:

```java
import org.pmml4s.spark.ScoreModel;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;

ScoreModel model = ScoreModel.fromInputStream(pmmlInputStream);
Dataset<?> resultDataset = model.transform(csvDataset);
```

BTW, PMML4S-Spark's license is APL 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for this! But it looks like this library can be used only along with Scala, not Java. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It definitely can be used in Java, see the example above in Java

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be totally irrelevant to your question, but since I faced an issue and was coming to this question again and again - I don't want others to face it. I reached to the solution some how by going through many stackoverflows...

### The problem

I was using spark in java using the old dependency maven code:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
    <artifactId>pmml-evaluator-metro</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Which I thought is perfect and will work. But that was **not recognizing** `TransformerBuilder` as one of its libraries.

The dependency code given below should solve your problem if your problem is related to TransformerBuilder:

```xml
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
          <artifactId>jpmml-evaluator-spark</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

That was it. You're welcome in advance